# Snort alerts analysis (web interface)

Tags: network, linux, ids, snort

I have a question about Snort (or maybe any other IDS/IPS, any working solutions would be ok).

The goal is to set up some web interface providing a way to view the whole TCP stream packets of each Snort alert. I'm interested in outgoing packets only.
Say, I have to prevent my server from replying with a string "*root:x:0:0*". So, I add a rule:

> reject tcp any any -> any any (content:"root:x:0:0"; flow:to_client;
>   msg:"attack1_to_client"; sid:31337)

and get my alerts logged. Alert log is growing fairly quicky. And I have to find all unique request strings leading to /etc/passwd disclosure, and block all such string.

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: The question: are there any projects available to achieve my goals?